# Elegant way to run nested loops in views (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-blade

I'm developing a site with Laravel that lists out scripts. In my view file I need to loop through the scripts, list children of the scripts that meet certain criteria separately. I'd like to contain all functionality in the controller, but I can't see how to pass information specific to looped scripts through to the view. See example below:

```
//CONTROLLER

 class ScriptController extends BaseController {

        public function instance() 
    {

        $scripts = Script::all();

        return View::make('script')->with(array(    
            'scripts' => $scripts
        )); 
    }




    // VIEW

    @foreach ($scripts as $script)
    TITLE: {{ $script->title }}<br />
    VOTES: 
    @foreach ($script->votes as $v)
        {{ $v['vote'] }}, 

        // This just lists out each vote (which is 1 or -1)
        // how do I count all 1's then all the -1's separately without a where query?

        @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

Ultimately, I'd need to do something like below in the view, or somehow pass the info through the controller.

```
    // IMPOSSIBLE VIEW

    @foreach ($scripts as $script)
        TITLE: {{ $script->title }}<br />
        VOTES: 
        @foreach ($script->votes as $v)
            GOOD VOTES: {{ count($v where $v['vote'] == 1) }}, 
            BAD VOTES: {{ count($v where $v['vote'] == -1) }}
        @endforeach
        @endforeach
```

Any ideas or fundamental controller concepts I'm missing?

**UPDATE**
Hope this clears up my issue a little bit. Last night I created a simple controller which perfectly delivers information including all the children classes of a single script that I'd need to display a single script. and can create that view perfectly.  Is there any way to loop that view.

Notice that I have to physically include a Script ID ($sid) in the controller to get this to work.

```
    //Controller Function

        public function instance() 
    {
        $sid = 27; //HAD TO PHYSICALLY INCLUDE SCRIPT ID
        $script = Script::find($sid);
        $user = $script->user()->first();
        $uid = $user['id'];
        $votes = array();
        $username = $user['username'];
        $good = Vote::good()->where('script_id', "=", "$sid")->count();
        $bad = Vote::bad()->where('script_id', "=", "$sid")->count();
        $voteQuery = Vote::where('script_id', "=", "$sid")->get();
        foreach($voteQuery as $v) {
                $votes[$v['user_id']] = $v['vote']; 
        }


        return View::make('script')->with(array(
            'script' => $script, //array
            'votes' => $votes, //array
            'user' => $user, //array
            'username' => $username,
            'good' => $good,
            'bad' => $bad

        )); 
    }
```

Then in my view to display a single script:

```
    //VIEW 
    TITLE: {{$script->title}}<br />
    UP VOTES: {{ count($good)}}<br />
    DOWN VOTES: {{ count($bad)}}<br />
    USERNAME: {{$username}}<br />
    @foreach($votes as $k => $v)
        {{ $k }} - {{ $v }}<br />
    @endforeach
```

Is there any way to loop this to display all scripts?  By looping through a $script_id array and passing it to the controller in each loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I would suggest that you preprocess your `$scripts` array in the controller before passing it to the view.

```
//CONTROLLER
class ScriptController extends BaseController {

    public function instance() 
    {

        $scripts = Script::all();

        // do good and bad vote summations
        foreach ($scripts->votes as $idx => $v ) {

            // initialize the counters
            if ( $idx == 0 ) {
                $v['Good'] = 0;
                $v['Bad'] = 0;
            }

            if ( $v['vote'] == 1 ) {
                $v['Good']++;
            }

            if ( $v['vote'] == -1 ) {
                $v['Bad']++;
            }

        }

        return View::make('script')->with(array('scripts' => $scripts)); 
    }
}
```

Then you can just display the ['Good'] and ['Bad'] counters when in your view.

Comment: I can't seem to get that working. 1. I'd need to pass arrays, within arrays, within arrays to the view and Laravel seems to have some issues processing that with blade.  I'm new to Laravel, but the cleanest method would seem to be to pass the information perfectly for one script via a controller, then loop $script_ids in the view and send to the controller. I guess my question is whether there is a way to pass a $script_id to the controller and loop the controller itself (See update to post).  Again I'm new, so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Thanks, after running into a problem with my own solution I defaulted to your concept.  With the actual code I included a complex array with script_id => 'user_vote_exists' key values, script_id => total_votes key value, and any other info I needed to pass.  So the only for each in the view was the actual scripts, then for script info I referenced the ID arrays to pull additional info.

Answer (score 0):

Whew. 24 hours on and off on this and here is:

As usually the answer is simple enough to make me feel dumb. I can loop through all scripts in the controller then by "echoing" the view instead of "returning" the view in the controller it renders the view multiple times.

```
//CONTROLLER

public function instance() 
{
    $allScripts = Script::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
    foreach($allScripts as $s) {
        $sid = $s['id'];
        $script = Script::find($sid);
        $user = $script->user()->first();
        $uid = $user['id'];
        $votes = array();
        $username = $user['username'];
        $good = Vote::good()->where('script_id', "=", "$sid")->count();
        $bad = Vote::bad()->where('script_id', "=", "$sid")->count();
        $voteQuery = Vote::where('script_id', "=", "$sid")->get();
        foreach($voteQuery as $v) {
                $votes[$v['user_id']] = $v['vote']; 
        }


        echo View::make('script')->with(array(
            'script' => $script, //array
            'votes' => $votes, //array
            'user' => $user, //array
            'username' => $username,
            'good' => $good,
            'bad' => $bad

        )); 
    }
}
```

Then the view can be the same

```
//VIEW

TITLE: {{$script->title}}<br />
UP VOTES: {{ $good }}<br />
DOWN VOTES: {{ $bad }}<br />
USERNAME: {{$username}}<br />
@foreach($votes as $k => $v)
USER ID: {{ $k }} voted - {{ $v }}<br />
@endforeach
<hr />
```